# Restrictning the limit of publush bassed on the _id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Currently i have this Publish function

```
Meteor.publish('Questions', function(limit, skip) {
  check([limit, skip], [Number]);
  var findAnswers = UserInfo.find({
    userId: this.userId
  }).fetch();

  return Questions.find({}, {
    _id: {
      $not: findAnswers.questionid
    }
  }, {
    skip: skip,
    limit: limit
  });
});
```

So bassicaly there are two Collections, Questions and userInfo (Aka User Answers hmm i think i will change the name) well so on the userInfo i have all the answers of a user.

Now im currently returning 1x1 questions to the user, and this works the limit(1) and the skip work, but now i dont want to send into the user the question that he already answer, i give a try to the $not operator but its still returning the question, to the client (a question that the user already answer).

is `$not` the correct operator here? also this will be scalable? lets say in the future the user answer answer 10 question, its there a need of an array? (holding the ids of the answered questions).

**Update**

Ive made something like this now.

```
Meteor.publish('Questions', function(limit, skip) {
  check([limit, skip], [Number]);

  var idsArray =[], //Ids array to hold all the current answered questions ids

    findAnswers = UserInfo.find({  //Simple query
      userId: this.userId
    }).fetch();

  _.each(findAnswers, function(id) {
    idsArray.push(id.questionid);  //forEach to push the ids on the query
  });

  return Questions.find({}, {  //Returning only questions
    skip: skip,                                      //with no answers to the client
    limit: limit
  });
});
```

Now i got an array of _ids, how can i just send the files that dont match the ids on the query?

**Second update**

So after some research i find that [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) could do the trick, but this seems to dont work anyways is still returning the 3 documents to the client

Here is more information.

This is my Questions Query.

```
> Questions.find().fetch()
[ { _id: '2eGSTigujteL4X7qG',
    title: 'Where you work?',
    body: 'Tell us about your job' },
  { _id: 'ByiJGwgHTm5dk5CBj',
    title: 'Where did you study?',
    body: 'Tell us about your where did you study' },
  { _id: 'gExyMfiivpb4ZtQTb',
    title: 'Did you have childs?',
    body: 'Tell us about your childs' } ]
```

Now this is my `idsArray`

```
 [ '2eGSTigujteL4X7qG', 'ByiJGwgHTm5dk5CBj' ]
```

And this is how im doing it on my query.

```
  returnQuestions.find({}, {
    _id: {
      $nin: [idsArray] //already try without []
    },                            
    skip: skip,                   
    limit: limit
  });
```

But this still returning the 3 objects to the client instead of just 1, this should only return the object with the `_id:"gExyMfiivpb4ZtQTb"` right? i dont see where is my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your last code snippet is a actual copy+paste from your code you have the wrong `find()` syntax (you put your selector in the options object and left the selector object empty). What you intended probably should look like something like this:

```
returnQuestions.find(
    {
    _id: {
      $nin: idsArray // assuming this already is an Array you of course shouldn't add brackets around it
    }, {                            
    skip: skip,                   
    limit: limit
  });
```

And `$nin` indeed should be the right operator for your case (also you maybe could use different approaches).